# RaspBMC black screen

Tags: raspbmc

I installed RaspBMC from a compatible SDCard and I got a black screen shortly after I saw the logo. After searching online, I realized that it might have been an HDMI problem so I went in the config file and added `hdmi_safe=1`.

Now I plugged the device back in and I get the same problem but while the logo screen is there, I see the following green text in the top left corner ". Ok"

Any ideas what might be causing this black screen?

Comment: how long have you left it? try unplugging all usb devices.